# There is a delayed lag when texture painting in 3D

Tags: texturing

can anyone explain this type of weird lag? (Smooth at first, then after 2 sec my computer fans start to spin and lags begin)
(texture painting)
(doesn't matter how small the brush size is)

https://i.gyazo.com/a332e2f73f5009af1a48f8574d398aa3.mp4

Comment: That happens to me from time to time, too. I don't know what it is exactly, but brush size and mirror seem to have an influence. Does it get better when you turn off the mirror/symmetry? (The mirror center does not seem to be in the middle for you.)

Answer (score 0):

This lag is normal, the thing is to paint in the UV image editor, directly on the image texture, and not in the 3d model, that way it has no lag.

Comment: but I've seen videos of people painting with no such lag. I rather have a slight constant lag than this!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution for this, the only way around is painting using the Uv editor, maybe those people in videos have like a powerful computer or their model was low poly with a smooth shader effect

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is due to a high face count on the model. There's a few tricks you can do to work around this though.

1. If your mesh doesn't have a subdivision modifier, what you can do is duplicate it, then apply a decimate modifier to reduce its polycount, and use that mesh to texture paint.

I demonstrate this below where my computer struggles to paint on a very subdivided Suzzane. I duplicate the mesh, give it a Decimate modifier, and I can then texture paint it smoothly. Just have to be careful not to decimate it too much otherwise where you paint won't match the higher polygon model.

[image]

2. If your mesh does have a subdivision modifier, blender offers some easy ways to reduce its polygon in the viewport to make models easier to work with

There's two ways to accomplish this:

- With the scene editor, change the max subdivisions in your viewport to 0 will remove any subdivisions you have active on your modifiers

[image]

- Alternatively, select your object itself and change the Levels Viewport to 0

[image]